# MySQL: Add index on column with condition and operation

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

In a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE date = LEAST(maxDate, '2013-12-31')
```

I am looking for an index that will be used during execution. `date` and `maxDate` are `Date` types.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use of function(UDF or built-in) in `WHERE` clause don't take advantage of existing indexes but you can modify your query like below which will be using the already existing indexes on `date` or `maxdate` (if there is any) column like

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE date = case when maxDate > '2013-12-31' then maxDate else '2013-12-31' end
```

Comment: Very clever Suggestion, thank you. Unfortunately an `HASH` index on `maxDate` or `date` is not used that way ...